# Green Screen on Everyplay Recording

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

I wanted to add everyplay to me game and using the prefab wich is in the EveryPlay folder everything went well until i saw the replay of the recording. It was a green screen. (Audio can be listen) Then the share and upload everything worked well.

I'm using Unity and a Samsung S4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the usual suspects (bad device, faulty codec etc), there's a chance you could be triggering an app specific issue with the graphics you're generating. In early development days there were Unity version specific issues, not to mention Android version specific ones.

The Q&A build bot / test runs we're having seem to claim that it should work a-ok.

Can you trigger the problem with Unity on a simple test scene (basic cube test)?

If possible, can you send a small test case triggering the issue to: support at everyplay dot com?